# Maven deploy to 2 different remote repositories

Tags: java, maven

I have some java projects which used maven build and upload artifact to nexus. It's working well. Now there are some changes in my company process so I need to upload artifact to 2 remote repository:

- Nexus
- Gitlab package registry

I try to define multiple profiles in pom.xml but it also pick 1 profile to deploy. Anyone have exp about this, please advise me

```
<profiles>
<profile>
  <id>profile-1</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>profile-1-repo</id>
      ...
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>profile-2</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>profile-2-repo</id>
      ...
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</profile>
...
```

```
mvn deploy -P profile-1,profile-2...
```

Comment: Why do you want to deploy to two repositories? You could just add the gitlab package registry as remote repository in Nexus, then everyone can access the artifacts through Nexus as well.

Comment: we want all projects in gitlab will use gitlab package registry not nexus. but we have some project artifacts still store in nexus, so I want to deploy 2 repos to use those artifacts in gitlab

Comment: Still I do not understand why you not just proxy one repository in the other instead of deploying twice.